# golang and maps in URL query string

Tags: go

Is it possible for Go's URL package to understand a map as a query parameter when using the `Query` method? Other languages would understand something like `filter_by[locale]=en_GB&filter_by[test]=yes&foo=12`.
The Query method seems to interpret this as `map[filter_by[locale]:[en_GB] filter_by[test]:[yes] foobar:[12]]`
I'm trying to pass along some filter names and values for a GET request.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question. The `url` package just parses standard query parameters, and what you've pasted confirms that (except for the discrepency between `foo=12` on your URL, and `foobar:[12]` in the result--which I assume is just a typo on your part). Do you need something different?

Comment: All I'm trying to understand is, if there is a way to pass a map in a query string. But since Query() produces a `map[string][]string` it's not really possible.

Comment: A query string _is_ a map. Beyond that, you can encode any arbitrary data into a query string, if you're creative enough. But there's no standardized method for doing so. You just need to do it in a way that your client and server both understand.

Comment: Thanks, I know a query string is a map. In case it wasn't clear in the question, I'm trying to pass map called `filter_by` inside of the query string map.

Comment: So what problem are you facing? Your question/problem still isn't clear.

Comment: How to construct the query string so that Query() would produce a map. I've just gone with splitting `filter_by` up into `filter_by_name` and `filter_by_val` arrays and them merging them into a map in my app.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "produce a map". Query() *does* produce a map. That's [the only thing it can produce](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that param may be array, like:

```
localhost:8000?foo[]=foo&foo[]=bar
```

and in this case you have to have `map[string][]string` so out of box you have this, and for example upper you'll have:

```
url.Values{"foo[]":[]string{"foo", "bar"}}
```